# Why can I get to use $format=json with entities but not with metadata using OData

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, wcf, odata

When I try this,

```
http://example.com/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata&$format=json
```

I get this error,

> "A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the acceptable
>   MIME types for the request. The supported type(s) 'application/xml' do
>   not match any of the acceptable MIME types
>   'application/json;odata=verbose'."

But when I try to access an entity like below it works,

`https://example.com/V3/OData/OData.svc/myExampleEntity?$format=json`

**Question**

Why $format=json work with entities but not with metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as the error has requested and make a valid request that references a mime type ...

http://example.com/V3/OData/OData.svc/$metadata&$format=application/json

... also supported is atom ...

http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/atom-format/

Comment: it doesn't work with generic error "Server Error in '/' Application."